# Find the general solution using the method of variation of parameters

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x'=$ $\begin{bmatrix}
    -1       & 1 \\
    -3       &  3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$x   + \begin{bmatrix}
    e^t \\
    1  \\
\end{bmatrix} $

Find the general solution using the method of variation of parameters

I am pretty comfortable with using the method of undetermined coefficients but I am having trouble solving it using VoP

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve linear systems of the form:

$$x'(t)=Ax(t)+b(t)$$

You first need to calculate the fundamental matrix $Y$of this system, by solving

$y'=Ay$.

You can get the fundamental Matrix by finding the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and eigenvectors $v_i$. $Y=[v_1,v_2,...,v_n]$ if $A$ is a $nxn$ matrix.

Then you use the Ansatz $x=Yc$, where 
$$x'=Y'c+Yc'=(AY)c+Yc'=A(Yc)+b(t).$$

As you can see we have gotten $AYc$ on both sides.

$Yc'=b(t)$ or $c'=Y^{-1}b(t)$

If you integrate the last expression you get $c(t)=\int Y^{-1}b(t)$. In your problem this will be a $2x1$ vector and $b(t)=(e^t,1)^T$.